# Update text in other Sheets based on text in Sheet 1

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

I have got a workbook with 62 worksheets. I would like to place the word Red, Blue or Green on Sheet 1, and when I do I would like a formula to automatically update the other worksheets with the words Red, Blue or Green.

So the worksheets are in order like this (Sheet1, Blue Sheet 1N, Red Sheet2, Blue Sheet 2N, Red Sheet3, Blue Sheet3N, Red Sheet 4, Green etc).

If Sheet 1 cell A1 = Blue then Sheet 1N cell A1 = Red and so on.

Answer (score 1):

So just put a variant of this formula in A1 on each worksheet:

```
=IF(Sheet1!A1 = "Blue", "Red", "")
```

Comment: This works fine but if I need to change (sheet 1!a1="Red","green") can you add it to this formula or "green","Blue" etc for use at a later date?

Comment: @Bryan, Yes, if you know up front all the combinations, you can just next the IF statements, like `=IF(Sheet1!A1 = "Blue", "Red, IF(Sheet1!A1 = "Red, "Green", IF(Sheet1!A1 = "Green", "Blue","")))`.

Comment: Thanks Lance it was just what I was after

Comment: @Bryan, if it was the answer you were looking for, then you can click the checkmark and "accept" the answer.